# ruby default parameters in function definition causing syntax error

Tags: ruby

What is wrong with the following method definition?

```
def method1(param1="val1", param2, param3="val3")
  #do something
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Default Values*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Default+Values) documentation is clear :-

Arguments may have default values:

```
def add_values(a, b = 1)
  a + b
end
```

The default value does not need to appear first, but arguments with defaults **must be grouped together**. This is ok:

```
def add_values(a = 1, b = 2, c)
  a + b + c
end
```

This will raise a **SyntaxError**:

```
def add_values(a = 1, b, c = 1)
  a + b + c
end
```

Answer (score -1):

In Ruby 2.1+ you can write like this

```
def method(a: '', b: , c: '')
  # your code here a, b, c
end
```